# which Wireguard MTU is chosen when each side has a different MTU value?

Tags: wireguard, mtu

***tl;dr*** given a Wireguard client and server with different `MTU` values, which value is used?

Given a Wireguard "client" with configuration file

```text
[Interface]
MTU = 1440
...
```

and a Wireguard "server" with configuration file

```text
[Interface]
MTU = 1420
...
```

which `MTU` value is used? In other words, is there a negotiation between them for a common MTU value?
Or does each side use exactly the `MTU` value it is given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both will be used, WireGuard does not negotiate MTU. The MTU value just tells the particular local WireGuard not to construct data packets larger than the value set.

Comment: Is there a way, using for instance `iptables` to override the peer's `wireguard` MTU config on server side?